# Common values for aliased chart dependencies

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have `Chart.yaml` as:

```
dependencies:
    - name: mysql
      version: "5.0.9"
      repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
      alias: a
    - name: mysql
      version: "5.0.9"
      repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
      alias: b
```

and `values.yaml` as

```
mysql:
  somename: Overriden
  somename2: NotOverriden
a:
  somename: A
b:
  somename: B
```

but the helm is reading only values from `a:` and `b:`. I would expect that values from `mysql:` are applied to both `a:` and `b:` and overridden where needed.

Is this possible at all, or is there some other way?

Comment: With yaml file you may reference value but helm doesnt support it if you want to set value while you install chart. I suggest you to use tpl function, by this way you may create generic values with or wothout condtion..

Answer (score 2):

You could use yaml anchors and aliases.

```
    mysql: &mysql
      somename: Overriden
      somename2: NotOverriden
    a:
      <<: *mysql
      somename: A
    b:
      <<: *mysql
      somename: B
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed the question but you can use global values:

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#global-chart-values

`values.yaml`:

```
global:
  somename: A
  somename2: B
```

btw, in your example you can't have the same dependency twice, helm will delete the first one:

```
❯ helm dependency build
Getting updates for unmanaged Helm repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami" chart repository
Saving 2 charts
Downloading mysql from repo https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
Already downloaded mysql from repo https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
Deleting outdated charts
```

Comment: Tried this, but seems that dependencies also need to have "global" section in their files for this to work. Other option was that I directly write properties to values files (so without global prefix) - and this one works to some extent, but the problem here is that it is also applied to other dependencies that I don't want to.

Comment: Isn't the point of `alias` to have the same chart multiple times?
https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#the-chartyaml-file

Plus that log output is just the fetching of the chart; the alias(es) are relevant to the usage of the chart i.e. application of the two set of values, `a` and `b`